# Checking if PDF is searchable

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, ocr, pdftotext

I wrote a bash script that extracts plain text from scanned PDF files. I've got lots of PDF's but some are scanned and some other are not. So now my main goal is to improve my script by checking if PDF's are already searchable, so no OCR extraction will be needed.

I've tried:

`pdftext -nopgbrk pdf_file.pdf wordlist`

to store possible OCR'ed text in `wordlist`, so then I can check if it's empty and figure out whether it's a searchable PDF or not.

I've also tried `pdffonts pdf_file.pdf` to check if there're fonts in that PDF and therefore if there's text on it or not.

Both ways work pretty fine but are failing in some cases.

For example, some of the PDF's I need to OCR are digitally signed, and those signatures always add a text layer to PDFs. So when I run any of those two commands, it'll output either the signature's text, or the font that it's using. It's like if it had found plain text just because of the signing. It might just be a scanned PDF with a digital signature, but it'll be detected as a plain text PDF.

Digital signings always add text this way (using Helvetica font):

*Signed by: Name*

*Date: Date CEST*

*Company: Company Name*

So with:

`pdftext -nopgbrk pdf_file.pdf wordlist | grep -v -E 'Signed|Date|Company'`

I can manage to remove those lines so if it's really a scanned PDF, the output will be empty.

It worked for some PDF's until I noticed a signature that had some other format, so I feel this is pretty much of a work-around and not a great solution.

Is there any way to check if a PDF is fully searchable? I just need a way to extract PDF's text but omitting digital signings. Also `grep -v` will always depend on our digital signature's format and if it changes then it'll screw up my script.

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably right. I posted this question with my OCR script in mind which is programing-related but then as you mention the issue I'm having itself might be off-topic, so the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange would have probably been a better place to post it. Anyway if someone showed up with a script or an algorithm to solve my problem then it could have also been related with programming. Sorry anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there really isn't an easy way to do this in a "non-hacky" way without significantly more involved analysis of the file which would be far beyond the scope and scale of a bash script.

When `pdftotext` outputs the text for the digital signature, that text is not coming from the digital signature itself. That is stored as an object in the PDF with metadata that `pdftotext` ignores. Instead, what `pdftotext` picks up is just that: text which has also been added to the file.

Here's an example from [Adobe's sample signed PDF document](https://blogs.adobe.com/security/SampleSignedPDFDocument.pdf). First, the digital signature's metadata:

[image: Screenshot of digital signature metadata]

And here is the text which is inserted into the document:

[image: Screenshot of text with same information as in digital signature]

Technically, you can have one without the other, and there is no established format for the text that generally accompanies a digital signature. Therefore, you're stuck either:

- Ignoring specific text with `grep`, as you are doing now, which can be unreliable.
- Running OCR on all files and then checking if there is a difference in the text before/after OCR, but then this defeats the whole purpose of checking in the first place.

Comment: To add to the last bullet point, some of the OCR tools we have include an option to "skip OCR on PDFs with searchable text layer".  So you would still run OCR on the whole set, but only image-based PDFs will be OCRed.  The result will be your existing files with text passed through untouched + image PDFs now with OCRed text.

Comment: @IlyaEvdokimov But in that case, though, wouldn't the processor ignore files that still need OCR, but happen to have a searchable text layer which contains only information regarding the digital signature? From what I understand in OP's predicament, that's the crux of the problem. It seems it would require some kind of more involved analysis that compares the text to the information in the digital signature, whether the PDF has images, and makes an educated guess as to whether or not to run OCR on that particular document.